# Codelite Build Error 'No such file or directory'

Tags: c++, codelite

Im new at programming with Codelite, i created some simple frames with wxCrafter, but Codelight will not install (yes, I have mingw installed, worked on a console program).
I tought, I made did a mistake with my frames, I decided to create a new project without changing anything and just build the project. I get the same error Code:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j4 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile
"----------Building project:[ Test - Debug ]----------"

Please use the --prefix flag (as in wx-config --prefix=C:/wxWidgets)
or set the environment variable WXWIN (as in WXWIN=C:/wxWidgets)
to specify where is your installation of wxWidgets.

Please use the --prefix flag (as in wx-config --prefix=C:/wxWidgets)
or set the environment variable WXWIN (as in WXWIN=C:/wxWidgets)
to specify where is your installation of wxWidgets.

Please use the --prefix flag (as in wx-config --prefix=C:/wxWidgets)
or set the environment variable WXWIN (as in WXWIN=C:/wxWidgets)
to specify where is your installation of wxWidgets.
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/user/Documents/CodeLite/Gravitation_Simulator/Test'
g++.exe: error: wx-config: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Error:: Invalid argument
g++.exe: error: wxWidgets: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: hasn't: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: been: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: found: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: installed: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: at: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: 'C:\Program: Invalid argument
g++.exe: error: Files'.: No such file or directory
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/main.cpp.o.d] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
g++.exe: error: wx-config: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Error:: Invalid argument
g++.exe: error: wxWidgets: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: hasn't: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: been: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: found: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: installed: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: at: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: 'C:\Program: Invalid argument
g++.exe: error: Files'.: No such file or directory
Test.mk:99: recipe for target 'Debug/main.cpp.o.d' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/MainFrame.cpp.o.d] Error 1
g++.exe: error: wx-config: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Error:: Invalid argument
g++.exe: error: wxWidgets: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: hasn't: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: been: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: found: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: installed: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: at: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: 'C:\Program: Invalid argument
g++.exe: error: Files'.: No such file or directory
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/wxcrafter.cpp.o.d] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
Test.mk:107: recipe for target 'Debug/MainFrame.cpp.o.d' failed
Test.mk:115: recipe for target 'Debug/wxcrafter.cpp.o.d' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/user/Documents/CodeLite/Gravitation_Simulator/Test'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
====1 errors, 0 warnings====`
```

Comment: New Project -> GUI -> wxWidgets GUI Application (wxFrame, using wxCrafter) -> Build (code isnt modified)

Comment: We don't all have access to your IDE and don't know what it generates through those steps you mention. So *please show the code*.  Also, have you noticed the repeated plea to "Please use the --prefix flag ..."? Have you considered that it might be a good idea to do what it says?

Comment: As I wrote, there is no code by me. I think this is a IDE specific problem, also because of the "please use...". But I dont know what this means or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with MinGW.
You need to have set the environment variables `WXCFG` and `WXWIN`
You can do this from within CodeLite: `Settings->Environment variales`

For example, if you installed wxWidgets development package under `C:\src\wxWidgets`

You should add 2 entries to the environment variables section in CodeLite like this:

```
WXCFG=gcc_dll\mswu
WXWIN=C:\src\wxWidgets
```

This should fix these warning for you.

Eran

Comment: Okay thanks for this, but i get this fatal error: "Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected. The library used 3.1.0 (wchar_t,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,wx Containers,compatible with 3.0), and your program used 3.1.0 (wchar_t,compiler with C++ ABI 1008,wx Containers,compatible with 3.0)." I used this wxWidgets library: [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codelite/files/Releases/wxWidgets-MINGW/wxWidgets-3.1-TDM-GCC-4.9.2_amd64.7z/download)

Comment: I just created a new post in the codelite forum, i think it is better to solve the problem there: http://codelite.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3413